# Finding WebElement Relative to Another WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find a webelement relative to another webelement that's not a child to the other using Selenium.  Here is a snippet of the source I'm working with ...

```
<td class="action" rowspan="7">
    <table class="action">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="topTr topTrPlainBg">
            <tr>
                <td class="middleLeftPlainBg" style="width: 4px;">
                <td class="caption" style="width: 99%; height: 215px;" colspan="4" title="Action properties">
                    <a href="javascript: var none=0;">Foo bar</a>
                </td>
                <td class="middleRightPlainBg" style="width: 4px;">
            </tr>
            <tr class="bottomTr bottomTrPlainBg">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
<td class="rule rulePlainBg" colspan="1">
    <table class="rule rulePlainBg">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="captionRule">Successful</td>
                <td class="plus">
                    <img src="https://mcc-69-77.usae.bah.com/sam/admin/vpe2/public/img/vpe-old/rule/plus-over.gif" title="Add item"/>
                </td>
                <td class="swap">
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

I'm trying to find the `img` element with the title "Add item" relative to the `a` element with the value of "Foo bar".  I know the element I'm looking for is going to be a child of the `td` immediately following the `td` that's the parent of the relative element.  Here's what I have so far (in Java) ...

```
WebElement fooBar = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Foo bar"));
fooBar.findElement(By.xpath("..//..//..//..//../td//img[@title='Add item']")).click();
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?  I've tried playing around with the slashes a bit but can't get anything to work.

Comment: Seems like two different tables to me?!

Comment: Check my answer on http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10014/selenium-webdriver-findelement-in-scope-of-webelement-doesnt-work

You have to start the Xpath with a dot.

Comment: @Saifur They are two different tables.  I still want to find an element in a table immediately following the other table though.

Comment: @user2150250 So, the location of `Foo bar` is always in **2nd** td then? or that changes?

Comment: @Saifur It should be, but should this even matter?  I'm just trying to step up 5 levels, then step into the very next `td`, and then find that `img` element I'm looking for ...

Comment: It should not be if the `xpath` is correct,. I am just thinking about the complexity of it. If you know for sure that the location of `Add item` is in 2nd `td` I would suggest you use `cssSelector` which is recommended over `xpath`. Would that be case though?

Comment: @Saifur I know for sure that the parent `td` containing the child element I'm looking for will always be the very next `td` after the other parent `td` containing the `Foo bar` child.

Comment: @FrederikDeMets I **DO NOT** agree with you. I use `xpath` without dot all the time

Comment: @Saifur Me too, but he asked for an Xpath relative to a WebElement, and that's how it works.

Comment: @FrederikDeMets ahh. ok. I see your point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you change the strategy a bit and use [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
//td[@class="action" and .//td[@class="caption"]/a[. = "Foo Bar"]]/following-sibling::td[contains(@class, "rule")]//td[@class="plus"]/img[@title="Add item"]
```

In selenium:

```
WebElement addItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='action' and .//td[@class='caption']/a[. = 'Foo Bar']]/following-sibling::td[contains(@class, 'rule')]//td[@class='plus']/img[@title='Add item']"));
addItem.click();
```

Here we are getting the `a` element with `Foo Bar` text checking parent's classes on the way. Then, for the first `td` parent getting the following `td` sibling with `rule` class. Then, getting the desired `img` element.

And if you want to start from the found `a` element, use [`ancestor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/ancestor) to find the `td` parent with `class="action"` and then apply the following sibling check:

```
ancestor::td[@class="action"]/following-sibling::td[contains(@class, "rule")]//td[@class="plus"]/img[@title="Add item"]
```

In selenium:

```
WebElement fooBar = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Foo bar"));
fooBar.findElement(By.xpath("ancestor::td[@class='action']/following-sibling::td[contains(@class, 'rule')]//td[@class='plus']/img[@title='Add item']")).click();
```

Comment: Would you mind spelling out both of your answers completely in the context of my question with the Selenium and everything?  Like having the `driver.findElement(By.xpath())` and all that?  Thank you so much.

Comment: @user2150250 sure, updated. As a side note, make sure Add Item is really clickable and smth will happen after a click on that `img` element.

Comment: Excellent and robust answer.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `xpath` you are using all I am seeing is that you are missing initial `//` so replace the `xpath` you are using with

```
//..//..//..//..//../td//img[@title='Add item']
```

Comment: Hey sorry, I had a typo in the code part of my post that shows what I've tried so far.  Now you can see how I'm trying to find the element relative to the other.

Comment: The initial `//` is not necessary as I'm looking for this webelement relative to the other, not relative to the over source. With the initial `//` in there, it's basically clicking the very first `Add item` in the entire html source.

Comment: @user2150250 I am not sure if that's the case though? Have you tried with `//`?

Comment: I did ... it's clicking the first `Add item` in the entire html source rather than the one in the `td` immediately following the `td` with the `Foo bar` child

Comment: OK. and I know you have mentioned that you want the relative element to the `Foo bar`. Considering the fact that you know the location of `Foo bar` is always 2 we can use this cssSelector `.rule.rulePlainBg td:nth-child(2)>img` as well